# How can I add the same column under additional condition?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, left-join

I have two tables with mangers and with clients.
So 'client' table has following fields:

```
1. id_client
2. email
3. name
4. id_manager
5. made_a_deal  (bool field)
```

And 'managers' table has following fields:

```
1. id_manager
2. name
```

These two tables are connected by id_manager key.

I want to get one table, which shows following fields:

```
1. id_manager
2. managers.name
3. COUNT(By field id_client)
And I couldn't make the fourth filed:
4. COUNT(By field id_client, which have bought something ('client.made_a_deal' is true))
```

My code is:

```
USE database_name;
SELECT
    managers.id_manager,
    managers.name,
    COUNT(client.id_client) AS `all`
FROM managers
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    client
    ON
    managers.id_manager = client.id_manager
GROUP BY managers.name
;
```

How should I modify my code to reach required table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, boolean columns are really integers with zero meaning `false`.

So try this line in your SELECT clause.

```
 SUM(IF client.made_a_deal  <> 0, 1, 0)) AS dealmakers,
```

If you're sure that every value in the `made_a_deal` column is either zero or one, this simpler clause will do.

```
 SUM(client.made_a_deal) AS dealmakers,
```

Comment: Cool! That's very simple and genius solution! Thanks!